# How do I get dynamic key values from an array in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic

```js
const jsonData = {
  a: '123',
  b: '456',
  c: '789'
}

type needArr = string[]


function test(obj: any, array: needArr): {
  [props: T in needArr]: string
} {
  const newObj = {};
  for (let item of array) {
    newObj[ item ] = obj[ item ] || '';
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

expect

const params1 = test(json, ['a']); // params1 get key a from jsonData

const params2 = test(json, ['a', 'b']); // params2 get type key a、b from jsonData

But now the grammar is wrong, what should I do to make the program work correctly

Answer (score 0):

A quick typing solution to make this work.

```
export type ValuesOf<T extends any[]>= Record<T[number], unknown>;
function test(obj: Record<string, unknown>, array: (keyof JSONDataType)[]): ValuesOf<typeof array> {
  const newObj = {} as Record<string, unknown>;
  for (let item of array) {
    newObj[ item ] = obj[ item ] || '';
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I pass only `a` for the second parameter, I want only `a` in type, not `?` value

Comment: @Mayness fixed the solution. think this is what you want